# Unit of size using in pdfmake library

Tags: pdfmake

what is the unit size used for pageSize in pdfmake :

```
var docDefinition = {
  // a string or { width: number, height: number }
  pageSize: {
    width: 595.28,
    height: 'auto'
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pdfmake uses **points (pt)** as a unit of measure (this goes both for page size and margin size).

In the source code of the library we can see that A4 paper is 595.35 x 841.995 pt.
Since A4 is 210 x 297 mm or 8.3 x 11.7 in, we can easily compute the conversion ratio.

1 mm = 2.835 pt

1 in = approx. 71.729 pt

See [this discussion](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/359) for more details.